# Loop through images in GUI Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a cell array of images I am trying to loop through in a GUI using a `'NEXT'` button, with two images on the screen at the same time. I have 9 images, each three are a series, and I have 3 series', such that I want to view 1 and 2, and 2 and 3, but not 3 and 1, which would be next in the list. I am having trouble coding this, so any help would be very much appreciated!

```
function next_block_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

handles.curr_im_fig = handles.curr_im_fig+1;
if mod(handles.curr_im_fig,(handles.maxblock))~=0
    p1 = handles.curr_im_fig;
    p2 = handles.curr_im_fig+1;
else p1 = handles.curr_im_fig +2;
    p2 = handles.curr_im_fig + 3;
end

imshow(handles.images_fig{handles.curr_im_fig},'parent',handles.axes1);
imshow(handles.images_fig{(handles.curr_im_fig)+1},'parent',handles.axes2);
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

Answer (score -1):

The most straightforward method I can think of is to keep the sequence of images to be shown in a matrix, and visit the matrix each time you want to show new images. Preferably, the matrix is arranged such that each row is the indices of two images to be shown at the same time. You can keep the row number of currently showing images in `handles` or `appdata` and advance this nunber each time the next button is clicked.

Below is a demonstration of the idea. You will need to preset `habdles.curSeqNum = 1;` in `OpeningFcn`.

```
function next_block_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

% Image sequence
mySeq = [1 2; 2 3; 4 5; 5 6; 7 8; 8 9];

nxtSeqNum = handles.curSeqNum + 1;
if nxtSeqNum > size(mySeq, 1), nxtSeqNum = 1; end

imshow(handles.images_fig{mySeq(nxtSeqNum, 1)},'parent',handles.axes1);
imshow(handles.images_fig{mySeq(nxtSeqNum, 2)},'parent',handles.axes2);

handles.curSeqNum = nxtSeqNum;
guidata(hObject,handles)

end
```